# Skype's big and small in-call windows

Tags: skype, skype-for-windows-10

During a call with regular Skype on Windows 10 I typically see two windows: the main one that would contain the other party's video or shared screen, and a small one that just has the other party's profile photo, plus a few buttons (e.g. end call, mute, or share screen). I do not have split view enabled.

If I mouse-over the Skype entry on the taskbar, it floats two small preview panes, one for each of those two windows ... but only sometimes. I have discovered that by dragging the main content window from monitor 2 to monitor 1 in my dual screen setup, I lose the preview of the smaller window, and it seems to disappear.  From there the process to find both of those windows gets quite confusing.

What are those two (big+small) windows called? Are there any options that control their behavior or visibility?